# "Access Denied" when rails connects to Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have did all the procedures as mentioned in several places and I also learned from lynda.com video tutorial. I used Mac 10.7 and I installed rubystack. I created the databases, add and checked the database.yml here is you can see it again.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  host: localhost
  database: simplecmsdevelopment
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: maiwandj
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Therefore, when I run rake db:schema:dump it print the following errors

```
bash-3.2$ rake db:schema:dump
/Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-18/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:220: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'simplecms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
/Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-18/simplecms/config/environment.rb:5:in `' Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => environment (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you granted permissions for that user on that database? i.e., `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON simplecmsdevelopment.* TO simple_cms@localhost;`

Comment: Yes, I have done the "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES" but I received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to grant permissions on the `simplecmsdevelopment` database for `simple_cms@localhost`:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'simplecmsdevelopment'.* TO 'simple_cms'@'localhost';`

You might want to change the directory permissions to something like 755 for `/usr/local/bin` as well...  That should fix the warning.

Comment: Yes, I have done the "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES" but I received the same error.

Comment: Check your database.yml, did you username "simplecms" instead of "simple_cms" somewhere? Error message displays the first, whereas your database.yml sniplet shows the latter.

Comment: No, it is correct, but let me tell you that when I create my rails project and I also created mysql database, but when I checked the file database.yml, there was no changed. The username was root, but I granted the simple_cms username.

Answer (score 0):

DB yml Config file mentions username: simple_cms, but error message in console mentions user 'simplecms'@'localhost'.... I would suggest you should rewrite db yml configurations. I guess you might be having wrong username ***'simplecms' written for test environment***.... most probably.... do check...

Comment: No, it was mistaken by the editor, but the original error is the same as simple_cms@localhost.